# How to filter DataGridView in my application

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have two grids that I set up using the winforms DataGridView wizard. One is bound to a trips table which is my transactions table and the other is bound to my expenses table. I know a little bit of linq2sql and I now have my expense table inserting with the fk(TripId).

What I want to do is filter the expenses grid based on the tripId. I am already retrieving the TripId PK of the currently selected trip so that part is done. I am just not sure how I would do the filtering considering I am using linq but used the built wizards to bind the tables.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have gotten this far with bluefeet's help below. The problem now is when I do my filter it just clears the grid instead of filtering based on pk. Here is the full code

```
 private void tripsBindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvTripGrid.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            //get selected row index
            int index = this.dgvTripGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
            //get pk of selected row using index
            string cellValue = dgvTripGrid["pkTrips", index].Value.ToString();
            //change pk string to int
            int pKey = Int32.Parse(cellValue);
            //int tripPrimKey = getPkRowTrips();

            this.tripExpenseBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("tripNo = {0}",    
            pKey.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mean filter or fill the expenses table based on the trip id?

Comment: I already have it filling all of the records from the expense table which includes the tripid. So wouldnt I just want to filter it?

Comment: I updated my answer below to include information on applying a Filter to a bindingsource.

Comment: a couple of questions, I don't know how your app works but do you need to display all of the Expense data initially? Or do you only want to display the data associated with each trip?

Comment: Only the data associated with each trip. i figured it would be easy to just bind the dgvExpenseGrid to the table using the wizard then just filter the needed data.

Comment: I suggest instead of doing a filter, then run a query against your database for the expenses associated with that trip.  So create a Fill where you would pass in the tripId to it and it would load the expenses at that point. Then you don't need the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to fill your second `datagridview` based on the selection in your first `datagridview`. This one way to do it:

- On the Load or Search of my first `datagridview`, use the event
  `DataBindingComplete` which then populates the second `datagridview`
  based on the id of the record selected in the first `datagridview`.
- Then if the selection in the first datagridview changes, I use the
  event on the `BindingSource_PositionChanged` to repopulate the second
  grid.

Code Sample

```
// this populates the grid.
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code to load your grid goes here
}

private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
     var drv = datagridview1bindingSource.Current as DataRowView;

     if(drv != null)
         // your method to load datagridview2 goes here if the selected row is not null
         LoadDataGridView2();
}

private void LoadDataGridView2()
{
   //populate datagridview2 using the selected row id from datagridview1
}

// finally when the position is changed on the datagridview1 binding source, then re-populate // the datagridview2
private void datagridview2BindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadDataGridView2();
}
```

this is a basic way to populate a second grid based on the selection in the first.

Edit:

Your comment says that you are filling the `datagridview` with all expenses, so to filter you will want to use the `Filter` property on the `BindingSource` for the `datagridview`. The `Filter` property allows you to view a subset of the DataSource.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx):

```
private void PopulateDataViewAndFilter()
{
    DataSet set1 = new DataSet();

    // Some xml data to populate the DataSet with.
    string musicXml =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
        "<music>" +
        "<recording><artist>Coldplay</artist><cd>X&amp;Y</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Under the Table and Dreaming</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Live at Red Rocks</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Natalie Merchant</artist><cd>Tigerlily</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>U2</artist><cd>How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb</cd></recording>" +
        "</music>";

    // Read the xml.
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(musicXml);
    set1.ReadXml(reader);

    // Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset.
    DataTableCollection tables = set1.Tables;
    DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

    // Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.
    DataGridView datagridview1 = new DataGridView();
    datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    this.Controls.Add(datagridview1);

    // Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
    // the DataView.
    BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
    source1.DataSource = view1;

    // Set the data source for the DataGridView.
    datagridview1.DataSource = source1;

    //The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
    source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'";
}
```

I use this type of Filter to show data based on account. For an account, I have a textbox when the user places the account number and I use the TextChanged Event to apply the filter. Then I have a button that is used to remove the Filter from the binding source.

You can apply the same thing to your expense datagridview using the tripid from your first datagridview.

Comment: I was hoping to filter since i am already filling but maybe that is not the best way... Anyway, I am not seeing an event for BindingSource_Position changed under my datagridview event properties

Comment: The event is PositionChanged and it is on the BindingSource object not DataGridView. But you can apply a filter if needed as well, it just depends on the path you want.

Comment: Ok thank you. For some reason I dont see any data on the grids when i apply my filter. Here is my code

Comment: this.tripExpenseTableAdapter.Fill(this.intranetExpenseDataSet.tripExpense);
            int tripPrimKey = getPkRowTrips();
            this.tripExpenseBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("tripNo = {0}", tripPrimKey.ToString());

Comment: if you debug is you tripPrimKey populated?

Comment: try this this.tripExpenseBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("tripNo = '{0}'", tripPrimKey.ToString()); put a single quote around your string value.

Comment: Nope. The expense grid just clears all data instead of filtering on the pk. Thanks for working on my other question with me as well! :)

Comment: can you edit your original question and post your code?  then I can get a better look at it.  And other people might see something that I am missing.

Comment: Okay it is edited. i took out the table adapter fill line tho because i didnt think it was necessary. thanks